# How to style axis in stacked bar chart-d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made a stacked bar chart by using the example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

My problem is that I want my page to have a black background and I can't seem to style the x and y axis with a different color. It seems like an easy task.

This is what I have tried:

```
   g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis_x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .style("font", "14px sans-serif")

    //this did not work. 
    .attr("fill", "#f00")

    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

I also tried to add a css property to the class 'axis'. That did not work. However, this worked to change the font size:

```
 .style("font", "14px sans-serif")
```

Also, in the same code for the legend, this did work to change the color of the legend:

```
   g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis_y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "s"))
.append("text")
.classed('x_axis', true)
  .attr("x", 2)
  .attr("y", y(y.ticks(10).pop()))
  .attr("dy", "0.35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")

  //this did not work. 
  .attr("fill", "#f00")

  .style("font", "20px sans-serif")
  .text("Calories");
```

So my question is why can't I change the color or fill of the x and y axis just like how I changed the color or fill of the legend.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEE https://plnkr.co/edit/f8SLs3kcL8ahmec1TrEg?p=preview

Actually the fill is being set internally by

```
 .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

From Docs https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/src/axis.js#L66
you can observe at line #66 and #72 thats being set by the axis function and see how itw wired at line #168 to return

but you can do it via a css solution like this

```
.axis g text{
  fill:#ffffff;
} 

 .axis g line{
  stroke:#ffffff;
}
```

But if you have multiple charts please make sure you add unique css class during this

```
 g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

So that you can use that class name as reference in css

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks!